# How solve the error 'ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 10 into shape (6)'?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, object-detection, vision

I want to train FairMOT
https://github.com/ifzhang/FairMOT

and I have this error, Traceback is this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 98, in <module>
    main(opt)
  File "train.py", line 69, in main
    log_dict_train, _ = trainer.train(epoch, train_loader)
  File "/home/sonic/sw/FairMOT/src/lib/trains/base_trainer.py", line 119, in train
    return self.run_epoch('train', epoch, data_loader)
  File "/home/sonic/sw/FairMOT/src/lib/trains/base_trainer.py", line 62, in run_epoch
    for iter_id, batch in enumerate(data_loader):
  File "/home/sonic/sw/FairMOT2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 819, in __next__
    return self._process_data(data)
  File "/home/sonic/sw/FairMOT2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 846, in _process_data
    data.reraise()
  File "/home/sonic/sw/FairMOT2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/_utils.py", line 369, in reraise
    raise self.exc_type(msg)
ValueError: Caught ValueError in DataLoader worker process 0.
Original Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sonic/sw/FairMOT2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/worker.py", line 178, in _worker_loop
    data = fetcher.fetch(index)
  File "/home/sonic/sw/FairMOT2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 44, in fetch
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/home/sonic/sw/FairMOT2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 44, in <listcomp>
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/home/sonic/sw/FairMOT/src/lib/datasets/dataset/jde.py", line 421, in __getitem__
    imgs, labels, img_path, (input_h, input_w) = self.get_data(img_path, label_path)
  File "/home/sonic/sw/FairMOT/src/lib/datasets/dataset/jde.py", line 188, in get_data
    labels0 = np.loadtxt(label_path, dtype=np.float32).reshape(-1, 6)
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 10 into shape (6)
```

the code is

```
    def get_data(self, img_path, label_path):
        ...
        # Load labels
        if os.path.isfile(label_path):
            labels0 = np.loadtxt(label_path, dtype=np.float32).reshape(-1, 6)

            # Normalized xywh to pixel xyxy format
            labels = labels0.copy()
            labels[:, 2] = ratio * w * (labels0[:, 2] - labels0[:, 4] / 2) + padw
            labels[:, 3] = ratio * h * (labels0[:, 3] - labels0[:, 5] / 2) + padh
            labels[:, 4] = ratio * w * (labels0[:, 2] + labels0[:, 4] / 2) + padw
            labels[:, 5] = ratio * h * (labels0[:, 3] + labels0[:, 5] / 2) + padh
        else:
            labels = np.array([])

        ...
```

I don't modify the FairMOT git code, I just use my own custom dataset. Thank you.

Comment: Okay, but what is your *question* about this? And where is the code that causes the problem? Please see [ask].

Comment: Okay, so. In your own words, when you do `.reshape(-1, 6)`, what do you expect that to mean? What should the loaded array look like before you do that? Next, *verify that*. Are you getting an appropriate input array from that file? No? So check the file.

Comment: (Hint: What is the remainder when you divide 10 by 6? How are you expecting this reshaping to work, exactly?)

Comment: You can't reshape a tensor to a new shape if the number of elements of the new tensor (10) is not equal to the number of elements in the old tensor(6)